# How to avoid the error in angular :- (node:19100) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental?

Tags: angular, warnings, fs

I am getting this warning when running the command ng serve. How can I uninstall fs-extra? Or what is the other way around to avoid this error?

Answer (score 3):

Update your Node.js version.

I was getting this warning in Angular v10 projects running on Node v10. I updated Node.js to LTS version (currently 14.5) and the warning was gone.

According to [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#prerequisites): Angular requires a current, active LTS, or maintenance LTS version of Node.js.

So basically it does work on version 10 atm, but it's always a good idea to update your environment if you can.

Comment: On Windows, redownload and install node from the website instead of using the command line, fixes it.