# Angular 10 how to fix warning: (node:27976) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

Tags: node.js, angular

I have upgraded my project to Angular 10 and when I run my project I get the following warning

```
 (node:27976) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
```

how can I fix it and what cause this change in Angular, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information regarding this bug [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/392).

You shouldn't use `import * from 'fs'` because it also loads unstable methods.

If you want to ignore the bug you can simply start your application via `node --no-warnings`.

Comment: I have not imported fs in my angular project, do you know where it comes from ?

Comment: Have you included a `* import` somewhere? If not, maybe a dependency is using it.

Comment: I used for the moment.js

Comment: Some modules use the new fs syntax which instead of using callbacks use promises. This is not stable yet and therefore the warning.

Comment: Upgrade node and it goes away [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685421/how-to-avoid-the-error-in-angular-node19100-experimentalwarning-the-fs-pr)